GeoNodes: Randomly translate and rotate leaves from a tree
I have a tree in which I want to be able to scale the leaves (smaller), add more leaves (copy them all because of current position) and randomly rotate and scale those.
I can scale them by using Scale Elements node, but I can't seem to rotate or translate them individually (and random).
I'd like to add density to the tree by adding leaves while scaling the original leaves down (because they are relatively big) and offset the leaves random by about 10cm and rotate them within certain bounds.
Best regards,
Harald
BTW: I've tried several more setups but keep getting the same results..




If you don't provide a "Group ID" to the "Split Instances" node, then all leaves will become a single instance.

Ah great, that did the trick.
That made it very slow though, maybe not the best way to do this.
I can continue my search for a good setup. Thank you so much, @MarkusvonBroady!

I think you want to transform them at the moment of instanciation (eg in the Instance on Point node) because now you're basically losing all advantages of instances
